# Can the Date Created metadata be changed after the fact on OS X?

Tags: macos, filesystem, metadata, file, movie

I have a movie file. It was taken back in October but the date created is from last week. How can I change the date created information in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following terminal command, which allows setting the date created:

```
SetFile -d "10/16/2012" file
```